# Where to place firebase-messaging-sw.js file in Play framework project?

Tags: scala, firebase, playframework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send a notification to the browser. I get the following error:

```
messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration", message: "Messaging: We 
are unable to register the default s…t. (messaging/failed-serviceworker- 
registration).", browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a 
ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP res…code (404) was received when fetching the 
script.", stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to 
 registe…/assets/javascripts/firebase/firebase.js:1:760104
```

What I understand from my google research is that the  firebase-messaging-sw.js is not in the root directory, I'am placing it under public/javascripts/. I'am using play framework for this project. My project hiearchy:

```
 |app(controllers, views)
 |public
 |conf
```

Comment: Have you tried placing it in `public`?

Comment: yes, but always the same error